# Appium Webdriver

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am new to Appium.I have downloaded all the required tools and able to set up environment variable. I try to execute my selenium script in mobile using Appium. But I got an error like below

```
 enterpackage appiumtest;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Appium {
    static RemoteWebDriver driver1;
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            opencalculator();
        }catch(Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();


        }
    }
    public static void opencalculator() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Babar Ali");
        cap.setCapability("UDID", "A6HU4TAQKZYD8L9P");
        cap.setCapability("PLATFORMNAME", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("PLATFORMVERSION", "8.1.0");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
        driver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);


        System.out.println("Application started....");

}
    }
```

Comment: Copy the stacktrace, don't insert pictures...

Comment: check it please

Answer (score 0):

In regard of my comment, a stacktrace is something like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) to see how to use it to identify your problems.

Regarding your problem, my guess is that your supplied URL is invalid: `http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub` whereas `0.0.0.0` isn't a valid IP:

> In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a
>   non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or
>   non-applicable target. This address is assigned specific meanings in a
>   number of contexts, such as on clients or on servers

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

If you want to use your local machine, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead.

A `0.0.0.0` *usually* means that an interface is bound to listen to every IP.